# iOS 11 blocking iframe content's links from from loading

Tags: html, ios11, content-security-policy

My content security policy is - 
"default-src 'self' *.validdomain.com

Most browsers including Mozilla and Chrome don't have issues hosting the iFrame and displaying it's content. Links are also clickable.

An iOS 11 device however, doesn't want to let the user click on the links that are within iFrame's contents from validdomain.com